# Usage of the "mousedown" event in JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, events, dom-events

What is the difference between jQuery `mousedown` method:

```
$(document).mousedown(callback);
```

and the usage of the `mousedown` event:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', callback, false);
```

Comment: "how to achieve a jQuery $(document) object using pure JavaScript?" That makes absolutely no sense. If you want a jQuery object, how else are you going to obtain one if not with the jQuery function?

Comment: `I notice that it is NOT equivalent` In which way it is not?

Comment: These 2 things *are* equivalent.  In fact, jQuery uses [`addEventListener`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.event.add) internally to bind the event.  P.S. Lose the `'on'` when doing `addEventListener` (that's only needed for IE's `attachEvent`).  It should be `document.addEventListener('mousedown', someFunction, false);`

Comment: Consider learning the basics of the DOM and its API. It'll help you understand what jQuery is and does, and when/where to use it or not. [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) has links to useful resources

Comment: Did that edit help address the new question, @Lior?

Comment: The issue in your `document.addEventListener()` code is that `"onMouseDown"` should be `"mousedown"`. No `"on"`, and no capitalization.

Comment: @Lior Why do you keep marking and unmarking my answer?

Comment: @Gavin42 I am sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't ask the right question in the first place and I'm asking to remove it. I apologize for any inconvenient.

Comment: Please do not remove the question. It is a valid question and has a working answer which can still be useful for other people. Please consider marking my answer as correct and leaving the question intact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(document)` is a jQuery object while `document` is a DOM object.

jQuery allows you to interact with the document as a jQuery object using the $() syntax only after jQuery is loaded. If jQuery is not loaded there is no way to treat it as a jQuery object, as that type of object is not defined.

There are a lot of things that you can do with `document` alone, HTML and javascript chief among them, but if you want jQuery functionality you have to include it.

A fantastic `document` vs. `$(document)` primer can be found [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/jquery-and-the-dom/0/1).

To answer the question in bold (**how to achieve a jQuery $(document) object using pure JavaScript?**):

You would have to rewrite the jQuery functions in javascript. It's not worth the effort, but definitely possible.

And, to address the edit:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.onmousedown = myMouseDownHandler;

    function myMouseDownHandler() {
      alert("A mouse down event took place within the document!");
    }
</script>
```

As @cookie_monster mentioned, if you want to use `document.addEventListener()` use `mousedown` instead of `onMouseDown`; without "on" and no special capitalization.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavin42/5ENK3/)

Comment: I doubt the OP understands what the `$()` syntax actually is. You make it sound a little like it's some sort of unique JavaScript syntax only found in jQuery. Maybe you should explain specifically what's happening there.

Comment: To my knowledge `$()` is a wrapper that adds jQuery functions to an object. The CodeAcademy link I posted should contain more detail.

Comment: It's a wrapper? No, that's not what it *is*.

Comment: I think he means that you should explain that `$` is nothing more than just a function provided by the jQuery library.  It doesn't "add jQuery functions to an object" or do anything too special, it's just a function that returns an object.  That returned object has some methods on it :-)

Comment: Thank you, @Rocket_Hazmat, for helping to clarify that.